# MP3gain suddenly broken... by Windows Update?

Tags: installation, redistributable

I have used MP3gain a bunch in the past, including just a few weeks ago.  But yesterday when I tried to run it again, it said it had a problem with the installation.

[image: System Error &H80004023 (-2147467229)]

Thinking nothing of it, I removed and reinstalled it.  However, during the reinstall, it told me that it was missing some of the install components and that I needed to get a new version.

[image]

I redownloaded the install package, but it was identical to what I had and produced the same error.  I tried running it on my laptop but got the same results.

Looking around online found almost nothing for that error.  I did manage to find [one Google group (in Portuguese)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ajuda-internet/01beSdsWMbY/JcZTrtxalvwJ) that suggested it was an error with the Visual C++ Redistributable package.  It does appear that there were some new updates to that recently, and when I tried to reinstall the older version, it wouldn't let me ("A newer version already exists").

Since MP3gain has not been updated in several years, I'm finding no where to go for help there, and don't have high hopes that he will randomly update the software to fix this.  Is there any way to make this work?  Downgrade VC++?  Do a side-by-side install?  Some weird form of Compatibility Mode?  (I tried several compatibility settings but to no avail.)

Then again, maybe I'm totally off-base here.  Has anyone else encountered (and fixed) this error before?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the suspect update? How about a system restore to a point before the updates applied? Depending on what changed in the libraries, you may have to look for an alternative to MP3Gain, and/or hope they fix it. Anyhow -- MP3Gain [Forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3gain/forums/forum/164668), [Bug Tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=49979&atid=458158)

Comment: I haven't tried to isolate the specific update, because there are too many that have come in since the last time I ran MP3Gain.  As much as I want this program to work, there are too many other things that might break if I tried to roll back to an indeterminate time.  Thanks for the links, though.